# Correct exponential output with printf

Tags: bash, printf, echo, tr

I try to write a script. With this script I need to remove return carriage at the end of the output numbers I parsed from some command output. So I need to transform them to integer. But printf won't format the number the way I want:

```
echo $var
2.80985e+09
var=$(printf "%s" "$var" | tr -dc '[:digit:]' )
echo $var
28098509
```

As you may see, printf removes the carriage but also modifies the value of variable. But I would like this value remain same, only return carriage is removed. Which parameter I should use with printf?

Thanks

Comment: What's "return carriage"?

Comment: some tab, enter, space at the end of parsed command output. So I can't use this variable for arithmetic calculation w/o remove it.

Comment: What, _precisely_, did you want the final value of `var` to be?

Comment: I misstated the problem. Actually I wanted printf displays the value of $var w/o exponential notation and tr removes correctly carriage return at the end. 

But when printf displays number as 2.80985e+09 . e + are also removed from the number so an incorrect output 28098509 is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want to do this:

```
$ printf "%f\n" $var
2809850000.000000
```

Or this:

```
$ printf "%f\n" $var | sed -e 's/\..*//'
2809850000
```

Comment: sed didn't produce the output I want but first worked for me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

`printf` did not modify the value of the variable; `tr` did.  You can verify this by:

```
$ printf "%s\n" "$var"
2.80985e+09
$ printf "%s\n" "$var" | tr -dc '[:digit:]'
28098509
```

The `tr` command, as given, removes all non-digit characters.

Answer (score 0):

Your `tr` command said 'remove every non-digit', so it did that.  You should expect programs to do exactly what you tell them to.  The whole `var=$(...)` sequence is bizarre. To remove a carriage return, you could use:

```
var=$(tr -d '\013' <<< $var)
```

The `<<<` redirection sends the string (value of `$var`) as the standard input of the command.

Comment: How I can see which carriage has the variable? Because it could be another carriage, not necessarily return.

Comment: @JavaRed: please note that the terms used in English are 'carriage return' (sometimes abbreviated CR), 'line feed' (sometimes abbreviated LF), CRLF (a carriage return followed by a line feed), and 'new line' (sometimes abbreviated NL, but actually synonymous with LF).  With that said, I'm not clear any more what you're worried about. Is the input data delimited with CRLF (as on Windows), or with NL (as on Unix)? Why are your inputs containing the CR? What characters are you trying to remove? Do you need to specify `tr -dc '[:digit:]-+eE.'`?

Comment: Sorry for confusion, maybe I used wrong explanation for correct term. Every variable contains \r at the end, so whenever I try to make some arithmetic calculation, shell takes them as a string but not as an integer.